# Fetching data only when the state changes

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching some data from an API and I want to fetch only when the state changes.

I have tried to include an empty dependency array to the useEffect but it is fetching everytime the component rerenders and I want the fetch to happen only when the value of the state changes.

Here is the code:

```js
      let [bestSelledBooks, setBestSelledBooks] = useState([]);
      const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(true);

      const getBestSelledBooks = async () => {
        try {
          setIsFetching(true);
          const data = await fetch(
            `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/overview.json?api-key=${key}`
          );
          const response = await data.json();
          
          setBestSelledBooks(response.results.lists);
          setIsFetching(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        getBestSelledBooks();
      }, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What state change do you want to trigger this? The only states included in the example are set inside the effect itself, so you would create an infinite loop if you were to trigger the request using `bestSelledBooks` or `isFetching`

Comment: const callApi = ()=>{
getBestSelledBooks()
}


Call callApi function only when the specific state is changes

Comment: Are you sure it is fetching every time the component re-renders?  `useEffect` with `[]` dependency is the equivalent of `componentDidMount` which is called only once, when the component is mounted, not on every re-render.

Comment: As Ergis mentions, if this is running every render, then the problem may be in a parent element that is destroying and re-mounting this component on each render.

Comment: Yes, it is fetching everytime. I added a console.log there and everytime I come back to the page where I am fetching this data the fetching happens again.

Comment: @xander17 did you try this inside the use effect     if(bestSelledBooks.length === 0) getBestSelledBooks();

Comment: When the page is first loaded I display a collection of books in the homepage with the data from that function. After I go to another page - about page let's say - and come back again in the homepage the book items are fetched again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, to fetch them only when page loads but after changing the routes and going to another pages and returning to the homepage the fetch function is called again.